# Plotting with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

With SymPy, I can plot a function with:

```
f, a = symbols('f a')
f = a + 10
plot(f)
```

However, if I define the function as:

```
f, a, b = symbols('f a b')
f = a + b
b = 10
plot(f)
```

Then I get an error stating:

```
ValueError: The same variable should be used in all univariate
            expressions being plotted.
```

How can I plot `f` if I define `f = a + b`, considering that `b` is assigned a constant value before plotting the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines

```
f, a, b = symbols('f a b')
f = a + b
b = 10
```

don't change `b` in the expression. If you print `f` you'll see that it is still defined as `a + b`.

You are confusing Python variables with SymPy symbols. In the first line, the Python variable `b` points to a SymPy symbol named `b` (in fact, they need not be the same name; you could have also written `x = Symbol('b')` and `y = a + x`). In the second line, the variable `f` points to a SymPy expression containing the symbol `b`. In the third line, the variable `b` points to the integer 10. This doesn't not change any previous lines that used the variable `b`, since they have already been run. It's no different than if you ran

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = a + b
b = 2
```

You would expect the value of `c` at the end to be `2`, not `3`. Similarly, when `b` points to a Symbol, expressions you create with it use a Symbol, but if you change it to point to a number, it doesn't affect previous lines from when it was a Symbol.

The recommended way to deal with this in SymPy is to avoid assigning the same variable to a symbol and then later to a non-symbol (it's worth pointing out that your definition of `f` in the first line is completely useless, since you immediately redefine it in the second line). To replace a symbol in an expression, use subs:

```
a, b = symbols('a b')
f = a + b
f1 = f.subs(b, 10)
```

Note that `subs` does not change the original `f`. It returns a new expression.

[This document](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html) may also help clear this confusion up.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't want to use substitution as in the other answer, you could make `f` an actual function of course

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b
a = symbols('a')
b = 10
plot(f(a,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You must substitute b into f:

```
plot(f.subs('b', b))
```

Comment: You should avoid using strings as input to SymPy functions.